# pimcore backend white screen registerNS Error

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, pimcore

Since yesterday I struggle with the backend of a website.
The website is still up and running, but as soon as I try to login in the backend. After the successfull login there is just a white screen. 
And in the console is the following Error.

[image]

Yesterday I changed just some HTML code. Does somebody know something about this error? Or is there a way to enable debug-modus in the code without the backend?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

This mostly happens when there is a failed response to one of the AJAX requests - the AJAX response gets mixed with an Exception message or error from backend.

Take these steps to figure out what ist the cause of the error:

- open Pimcore backend
- open Developer Tools
- reload Pimcore backend
- switch to the network tab of the developer tools
- click on the ajax button in the network tab to only display AJAX requests
- carefully examine all the responses to see if any of them have either failed or have an error message in them

I hope this helps you further.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but all ajax response are OK (200). maybe I habe to try to update pimcore to avoid this error.

Comment: Eventhough the responses have status 200, look into the actual response body. I am pretty sure you will find some malformed JSON somewhere in there, including the actual error message.